# Do I need to separately test on iPod touch, iPad and iPhone?

Tags: ios, testing, compatibility

I would like to start developing for iOS. Coming from an Android developing background, I know that the more types of devices you can get your hands on, the better testing will be, as all devices have wildly different specs, and what may work perfectly in your test device may not even run in another one, let alone look good.

I know that testing on the actual device is very important, as there are many limitations on what you can test on an emulator, so I've decided to get an actual device.

However, there are also tons of devices available in the iOS world! There's the iPod touch, the iPad and the iPhone, each in several different generations and configurations (8GB version vs 16GB version, WiFi version, 3G version, etc.). Not also the screen sizes, but also the aspect ratio is very different across devices, and also the included sensors.

I think that getting an application to *run* in varied devices should not be difficult, but is it necessary to actually test on all the device types you plan to support? Apple is not renown for its low price, and I would like to keep the starting costs as low as possible.

So, to conclude: Is it necessary/recommended to test on as many device types as you can in the iOS development world?

A small clarification: I'm specially asking if it is possible for there to be compatibility issues related to a specific device/family-of-devices that I would not be able to catch either by testing on the emulator nor a totally different device.

Comment: I don't think you need every device. Maybe get an iPod touch, a basic iPad, and use the simulator.

Comment: @Scott um yeah, it is precisely because I want something more than just a hunch that I made this question.

Comment: Well, my comment was not based on a hunch but rather experience.

Comment: @Scott well, "don't think" and "maybe" are words usually used when describing hunches, while numbers, technical reasons and specs are much more preferable when answering a question in here. Just my 2 yen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, the major differences in capabilities between testing on the simulator and testing on a device are:

- The simulator does not use exactly the same sandboxing as the device.  So, for instance, if your provisioning profile is missing your Passbook credentials, this problem will show up on a physical device but not on the simulator.
- The simulator doesn't generally support GPS, multitouch, push notifications, Bluetooth, and some other specific features.
- On a non-retina display, the simulator view for an iPhone 5+ or (especially!) a retina iPad will be nigh unusable at 100% because its size will exceed the size of your screen.
- There are a few, very rare, crashes that occur only on the simulator and a few that occur only on the device.
- The simulator does not always support the earliest iOS versions your app supports.  For instance, the current version of Xcode (which you must use if you want to build for the latest iOS version) only has simulators from 5.0+ available.
- Certain profiling with Instruments is, as far as I can tell, only available in the Simulator.

Now, in my specific case, I try to test on one of each screen resolution I support and one of each *major* OS version I support.

This boils down to the following array of test devices:

- (480x320) iPhone 3GS running 4.3.3
- (1136x640) iPod 5gen running the latest 6.x
- (960x640) iPhone 4S running 6.0
- (1024x768) iPad 1st gen running 5.0
- (2048x1536) iPad 4th gen running the latest 6.x

Note that the iPad mini is the same resolution as the iPad 1st gen.

(My choices are skewed towards later iOS versions since I like to implement integration with all of Apple's snazzy optional features as they roll them out.  It would probably be a more balanced assortment if one of the 6.x devices were running 5.1 instead.)

If you don't *need* to support 4.x, I would personally advise against it, since iTunes Connect no longer collects crash reports for it and the simulator no longer offers it.  Of course, only you can decide whether you really *need* to or not, and if you do, focus a lot of your testing there as Xcode does not warn you if you are using APIs that were only introduced in 5.0, which will crash any device running 4.x.

Please note that there are ways to (with significant preparation) downgrade the version of iOS on a device, so if you really want to test more versions than you have devices for, you can (with a lot of effort).  But you're probably better off cultivating a strong pool of beta testers for this, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it's obviously great to test on all possible devices, the iOS ecosystem is *much* tighter than Android, so you can narrow down the field somewhat.

You can start by limiting your target iOS versions. That will anyway cut out a number of older devices.  iOS6 share of all iOS devices is now probably around 75% 4 months after release; iOS5+iOS6 upwards of 90%. If you are just now starting to develop for iOS, you could probably just target iOS6.

That means your minimum hardware platform is iPad2 / iphone3GS / ipodTouch4

Total list of devices

```
iPad:   2 3 4 mini
iPhone: 3GS 4 4S 5
iPod:   4 5
```

Ten devices.

But you won't need to test them all. You could sensibly narrow it to...

```
iPad:   mini + one of the retina models
iPhone: 3GS + 5
```

for everyday testing.

Obviously if you *do* want to be more back-compatible, just replace the lower-end testing model for a lower-spec device (iphone 3, iPad 1).

The difference in storage capacity (8GB vs 16GB for example) will be mostly immaterial.

There are some hardware features you will have to pay special attention to, depending on your project. The obvious one is retina vs non-retina displays. Hardware features for location services is particularly nuanced between models.

Lowendmac have a pretty thorough [iphone comparison chart](http://www.lowendmac.com/iphone/iphone-comparison.html)...

Answer (score 2):

> I think that getting an application to run in varied devices should
>   not be difficult, but is it necessary to actually test on all the
>   device types you plan to support?

That depends a lot of what kind of apps you intend to build. For example, universal apps run on both small- and large-screen devices but may present themselves differently on each, so you'd want to be able to try both. Many apps target iPad specifically, so obviously testing on small devices isn't necessary. iPod Touch and iPhone are very similar, so testing on one or the other is often sufficient.

In short, you don't have to own every version of every device, and you don't probably don't have to test on every single version of iOS that's ever been released. But you do want to get your product tested on as many different devices and operating system versions as you can. So, cultivate a group of beta testers who will help you out by trying your app on their devices. The iOS developer program lets you add up to 100 test devices to your account precisely so that you can get your app tested in lots of different circumstances.

Comment: Interesting thing, asking a bunch of other people to help you test your app. However, device-specific problems wouldn't be solvable unless you can also ask that person to give you his device for further testing.

Comment: Not necessarily. Your testers can send you crash logs which sometimes provide enough information to solve problems. You can also add instrumentation to test versions of your app to collect performance information and such. And testers themselves can provide valuable feedback.

Comment: Well, it is of course very useful, to have as many testers as possible. I'd just not use other people as my first line of testing though.

Comment: Of course -- you test on the simulator and on the devices that you do have. But most developers don't have the resources to have a copy of every version of every iOS device. And it's really not necessary anyway -- the number of devices is far smaller than in the Android world, and they're much more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Testing on the iPod touch is generally not worth it.

In the iOS world, there is generally the iPhone/iPod, the iPhone 5/iPod 5th generation, and the iPad.

So, that is a total of 3 screen sizes.

If you plan on targeting more than the latest OS (iOS 6), that is where the complexity of testing comes in. Simply targeting iOS 5, and iOS 6 nearly doubles the amount of targets you need to test for.

I try and keep it simple. I test on my iPhone 5, and my iPad. Both of those run iOS 6. For iOS 5 and the small iPhone, I rely on the simulator.

Comment: Well, the main (probably naive) advantage of the iPod is that it's cheaper than the iPhone, and getting an iPhone most likely involves signing a contract with a mobile operator, which is irrelevant for  testing purposes unless I was making a networked app that specifically has to work over 3G.

Comment: True, but the iPhone is also a phone ;-)

Comment: ... which is irrelevant unless I was making a networked app that specifically has to work over 3G

Comment: You are correct, I was just pointing out the fact that you've got to have a phone anyway... Just being light hearted, don't take it too seriously :-)

Comment: Unless I just came in from the stone age, it is very likely that I already have a phone (a Galaxy Note 2, by the way)

Answer (score 0):

I develop for both Android and iOS, so I get where this question is coming from.  I have the luxury of being able to develop on most of the different iOS devices and I would say that in most cases I would feel comfortable testing on the least advanced device my user will be using.  If it runs smooth on a iPOd 3rd gen then it is going to run very smooth on an iPhone 4S, 5, etc.  For the different screen height for the iPhone 5, the simulator works very good with laying it out.

Things you will need to consider is if your apps have the option to use certain feature only a phone would have, like making calls.  Also if you want to make a iPad or universal app, it would be very handy to have an actual iPad, but the simulator does work very good.